# React Native app connection to mysql - API for production

Tags: mysql, react-native, api, rest, mobile

I have created my first app using expo and react native.

My backend is written in node.js (with express and axios) and connected to mysql database. I will be using get, post and put.

What I don't understand is how I move from a development environment to a production environment. In order to connect my API to an external server how do I go about setting up a baseURL which would replace my IP address and port in the below example?

```js
Axios.post("http://53.183.245.150/:19056/location", body).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
}).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

I have searched online and all examples which they create an API only include running off the local server rather than creating a production app and setting up a remote server.

I would like to link the mobile app to my existing production DB (using mysql) and running off AWS. This DB is connected to my website which is up and running. My backend for my website is written in PHP.

Thank you for any guidance!

I have attached an example of my server as well.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    user:'root',
    host:'my ip address here',
    password:'',
    database: 'myDB',
});

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {

        const user = req.body.user;
        const password = req.body.password;

    db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsers = ? AND pwdUsers = ?', [user, password], (error, rows, fields) => {
        if (error) console.log(error);
        if (rows.length > 0) {
            res.send(rows);
        } else {
            res.send(rows);
        }
    });
})

app.get('/trips', (req, res) => {

        const driver = req.query.driver;
        const companyId = req.query.companyId;
        const status1 = req.query.status1;

    db.query('SELECT * FROM trips WHERE driver = ? AND company_id = ? AND status_1 = ?', [driver, companyId, status1], (error, rows, fields) => {
        if(error) console.log(error);
        else{
            console.log(driver)
            res.send(rows);
        }
    })
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 19056;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
})
```

Comment: So basically you want to set your backend url as an environment variable?

Comment: I’m actually just trying to understand how you create/setup a backend URL